# 'Less than' comparison with tolerance

Tags: matlab, math, precision, numerical

I am trying to write some code that computes whether `a` is less than `b` with n-bit tolerance, where `a` and `b` are double precision variables.

For example, `4.000000001 < 4.00000001` would be `TRUE`, but `4.0000000001 < 4.000000001` would be `FALSE`. `3.99999999 < 4.00000000` would also be `FALSE`. Also note that `a` and `b` could be negative.

Comment: Do you want to compare with a certain tolerance, or really the first n digits? 4.000000000<3.9999999999 will not be true, but is a very common derivation.

Comment: I'm sorry, i phrased it incorrectly. I meant to say with n-bit tolerance

Comment: You might have a look at [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html).  You can get a variety of tolerances appropriate for different data types (e.g. `eps('single')`)

Comment: None of the answers worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
ndigits = 7;
round(a*10^ndigits) < round(b*10^ndigits)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really look for a `<` relationship, I would do

```
x < y + tolerance
```

where tolerance is a value which indicates which values *above* `y` shall count as *below* it.